# Merging two queries does not return all available records

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble merging two query results into an array - the merged output contains all the records of one of the queries ($factsheets) but only the last record of the other ($actives) where there are usually at least 3 records "available" to return.

My controller's code is as follows:

```
public function show($pest)
{
  $theactives = self::getActives($pest);
  $thefactsheets = self::getFactsheets($pest);

  $merged = $theactives->merge($thefactsheets);
  $result = $merged->all();
  return $result;
}

public function getActives($pest){
  $actives = Active::where('pests.id',$pest)
    ->join("active_pest","actives.id","=","active_pest.active_id")
    ->join("pests","pests.id","=","active_pest.pest_id")
    ->select('ai', 'groupcode', 'risk', 'pest')
    ->orderBy('ai')
    ->get();
  return $actives;
}

public function getFactsheets($pest){
  $factsheets = Factsheet::where('pest_id',$pest)
    ->join("factsheet_pest","factsheets.id","=","factsheet_pest.factsheet_id")
    ->select('title', 'factsheets.id')
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->get();
  return $factsheets;
}
```

Again, my expectation has exceeded my ability - what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't merge objects of the result set. So, you have to convert your result into array first before the merge. Try the below script.

```
public function show($pest)
{
  $theactives = self::getActives($pest);
  $thefactsheets = self::getFactsheets($pest);

  return array_merge($theactives, $thefactsheets);
}

public function getActives($pest){
  return Active::where('pests.id',$pest)
    ->join("active_pest","actives.id","=","active_pest.active_id")
    ->join("pests","pests.id","=","active_pest.pest_id")
    ->select('ai', 'groupcode', 'risk', 'pest')
    ->orderBy('ai')
    ->get()->toArray();
}

public function getFactsheets($pest){
  return  Factsheet::where('pest_id',$pest)
    ->join("factsheet_pest","factsheets.id","=","factsheet_pest.factsheet_id")
    ->select('title', 'factsheets.id')
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->get()->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Narayan, that provided the solution. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union in laravel

example

```php
$silver = DB::table("product_silver")

    ->select("product_silver.name"

      ,"product_silver.price"

      ,"product_silver.quantity");



$gold = DB::table("product_gold")

    ->select("product_gold.name"

      ,"product_gold.price"

      ,"product_gold.quantity")

    ->union($silver)

    ->get();

then
dd($gold);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, in the context of my situation, the different number of columns in the two selects causes an error (Cardinality violation).